# Keyword/method to reference current method

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to pass the current method as a parameter using Reflection?
In other words, is there something like the `this` keyword, but for methods?

For example:

```java
class ReflectionUtils {
  public static void printMethod(Method method){
    System.out.print(method.getName());
  }
}

// then...

class callerClass {
  void callerMethod(){
    ReflectionUtils.printMethod(/* "this" but for methods */)
  }
}

// would print: "callerMethod"
```

I want to pass `callerMethod` from itself to the `printMethod` method. Is there any way to do this, without parsing the stack trace?

Comment: Java 8+ has method references but you can't pass them to a `PrintStream` like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no keyword for that.

I do not know your exact needs, but you could also do this using [Class#getEnclosingMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod--) like that:

```
Method enclosingMethod = new Object() {}
                              .getClass()
                              .getEnclosingMethod();
```

It is similar to the way you proposed.

Comment: Not very elegant, but I feel like it will do the job. Thanks!